# C# Form_Load event method

Tags: c#, winforms

In C#, what is Form_Load event method?

Answer (score 8):

It is just a method name, its actual name doesn't have any significance.  You'd typically use a method with a name like that to listen for the Load event of the Form class.  The Winforms designer auto-generates it when you use the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window or when you double-click the form in the designer.  The name is more typically Form1_Load.  But do make it a practice to give the form a good Name first.  Like MainWindow.

The Load event fires just before the window becomes visible.  It is useful because at that point the real window size and location is accurate, you might want to use it to move or size controls.  Or anything else where the window size and location matters.

Implementing the Load event for a Form is an anachronism that dates back to the VB6 days.  Events are meant to let code in *other* classes know what's happening.  The Winforms way is to override the OnLoad() method instead.  The designer favors the VB6 way though.  It isn't terribly wrong when you don't derive from the form.

Answer (score 4):

It's the method called [when a form is first created and loaded for display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx), if the method is bound to that event.

Note that it can have any name, but the important thing is that it is bound to a form's `Load` event.

Answer (score 0):

It is the method that is called when the form is opened/loaded.

You can change the name of the method, so long it is still bound to the Form's Load event in the Form Designer's auto generated code.